# Intercepting drawerLayout before it consumes windowinsets

Tags: android, android-layout

I know DrawerLayout automatically consumes windowInsets by its own behaves.
Does this means if root layout is drawerLayout then i can never receive windowInsets?

If "rootView" is ConstraintLayout and everything works great,
but when i change "rootView" to DrawerLayout and constraintLayout becomes its sub view, then windowInsets listener is never works.

```
rootView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION


        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(toolbar_main) { _, inset ->

            // This callback never triggers.

            LogUtil.d(TAG, "inset top : ${inset.systemWindowInsetTop}")

            toolbar_main.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
                topMargin = inset.systemWindowInsetTop
            }

            currentY = (toolbarHeight + inset.systemWindowInsetTop).toFloat()

            recyclerView_music.updatePadding(top = toolbarHeight + inset.systemWindowInsetTop)

            inset
        }

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(recyclerView_music) { _, inset ->
            recyclerView_music.updatePadding(bottom = inset.systemWindowInsetBottom)
            inset
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhhh..

I found out that DrawerLayout does not need to set fitsSystemWindows=true,

and it still work.

When I remove fitsSystemWindows property and windowInsets listener works.